# Powershell RegEx not being invoked on piped output

Tags: regex, powershell

Developed this statement on my primary workstation where it (correctly) outputs a delimited textfile:

```
type output.tmp | -match /r /v "^-[-|]*-.$"  >  output.csv
```

Now, working on my laptop (same win8.1) where supposedly all the same PS modules and snapins are loaded, it tosses an error:

```
-match : The term '-match' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
```

Yet:

```
"Software" –match "soft"
```

works.

1) Why?

2) Is there a PS commandlet I should invoke to be able to get a more verbose/helpful error output?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To get obnoxious amounts of debug output, `get-Help Set-PSDebug`
2. You simply need to add the following:

   `type output.tmp | ? { $_ -match /r /v "^-[-|]*-.$" }  >  output.csv`

Or the more powershell-y way:

```
Get-Content -Path:"Output.Tmp" | Where { $_ -match "^-[-|]*-.$" } | Out-File -FilePath:"output.csv"
```

Answer (score 2):

`-match` is an operator on two arguments (one placed before one after the `-match`).

But at the beginning of each pipeline segment you need a command (including cmdlets)<sup>1</sup>.

There are two approaches:

1. Wrap the `-match` into a cmdlet like `foreach-object` (or its `%` alias):

   ```
   ... | %{ $_ -match $regex } | ...
   ```

   remembering that `-match` returns a boolean, not the matched text.
2. Use `Select-String` which is a cmdlet explicitly included for searching text. This does return the matched text (along with some other information), and can read a file itself:

   ```
   Select-String -Path $inputFile $regex
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking: *except the first*, which can be any expression.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that `match` is a [comparison operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx), not a cmdlet:

> Comparison operators let you specify conditions for comparing values
>   and finding values that match specified patterns. *To use a comparison
>   operator, specify the values that you want to compare together with an
>   **operator that separates these values***.

Also:

> The match operators (-Match and -NotMatch) find elements that match or do not match a specified pattern using regular expressions.
>
> The syntax is:
>
> ```
> <string[]> -Match <regular-expression>
> <string[]> -NotMatch <regular-expression>
> ```
>
> The following examples show some uses of the -Match operator:
>
> ```
> PS C:\> "Windows", "PowerShell" -Match ".shell"
> PowerShell
>
> PS C:\> (Get-Command Get-Member -Syntax) -Match "-view"
> True
>
> PS C:\> (Get-Command Get-Member -Syntax) -NotMatch "-path"
> True
>
> PS C:\> (Get-Content Servers.txt) -Match "^Server\d\d"
> Server01
> Server02
> ```
>
> The match operators search only in strings. **They cannot search in arrays of integers or other objects.**

So, the correct syntax is:

```
@(type output.tmp) -match "^-[-|]*-.$" > output.csv
```

*Note: Just as @mjolinor suggested, the `@` prefix forces the `(type output.tmp)` into an array, just in case that the input file contains only one line.*

Comment: I don't think that second option is going to produce the desired output.  -match works differently on scalars and arrays. The first one will act as a filter, the second one is going to produce a stream of booleans.

Comment: One more quibble. Need to add @ to the beginning of that to force it to an array in case there's only one line in output.tmp.